# Enabling root access for an app (TeamViewer) on Android Marshmallow 6[Moto G]

Tags: rooting, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g, teamviewer

I am attempting to use Teamviewer(control my Android phone from a Windows PC)

Using the host Teamviewer App I can currently see the screen but not control it, some of the reviews say it requires root access enabling fo the app.

How can I enable root access for a certain app?
Does the Motorola Moto G come with any root restrictions (one of the reviews says Motorola has a root issue)?

Comment: 1) is your device rooted at all? 2) if the app doesn't ask for root access, you cannot "enable root access" for it.